# Firebase - Imported user from another account is not able to login

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-authentication

Requirement:
Export users from a firebase account to a different account

How I exported:
Using terminal and Firebase CLI, with the following script
`firebase auth:export export.json --format=json --project <valid project id>`

This gives me a json file with all the users.

Code to import

```
    import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
import base64

cred = credentials.Certificate("service.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def import_with_scrypt():
    users = [
        auth.ImportUserRecord(
            uid='KmlKsGPEDiWtGMkwYyA4VlhLAQ43',
            email='testme@test.com',
            password_hash=b'base64 key',
            password_salt=b'base64 key'
        ),
    ]

    # All the parameters below can be obtained from the Firebase Console's "Users"
    # section. Base64 encoded parameters must be decoded into raw bytes.
    hash_alg = auth.UserImportHash.scrypt(
        key=base64.b64decode('base64 key'),
        salt_separator=base64.b64decode("base64 key"),
        rounds=8,
        memory_cost=14
    )
    try:
        result = auth.import_users(users, hash_alg=hash_alg)
        for err in result.errors:
            print('Failed to import user:', err.reason)
    except auth.AuthError as error:
        print('Error importing users:', error)

import_with_scrypt()
```

Problem:
This successfully imports the user to the new firebase account.
When I try to login to this user account within the new account, with existing user credential,

It throws an error

> auth/wrong-password The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and was able to resolve it by using the [crypto npm package](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). Keep in mind my solution is in NodeJS, but you should be able to translate this to python. I created this as a cloud function, but the concept is still the same regardless of how you pass in your data:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import { IAuthUser } from '../models/auth-user.model';

export const importUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    let users = new Array<IAuthUser>()

    // Map user data with generated password hash/salts
    req.body.users.map(user => {
        let authUser = user as IAuthUser
        const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16)
        authUser.passwordHash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(user.password, salt, 100000, 64, 'sha256')
        authUser.passwordSalt = salt
        users.push(authUser)
    })

    // Send to Firebase Auth
    admin.auth().importUsers(
        users,
        {
            hash: {
                algorithm: 'PBKDF2_SHA256',
                rounds: 100000
            }
        }
    ).then(function (results) {
        results.errors.forEach(function (indexedError) {
            console.error('Error importing user ' + indexedError.index);
        });
        res.send(results)
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give this a try (y)

Comment: Can you explain `import { IAuthUser } from '../models/auth-user.model';` this line? What does your model object consist?

Comment: IAuthUser is just an interface that mirrors the Firebase Auth user model:

`export interface IAuthUser{
    uid:string;
    email:string;
    passwordHash:Buffer;
    passwordSalt:Buffer;
}`

Comment: Hi @Nina, did the suggestion from Sentient Entities work for you?
I seem to be running into a similar issue using the ***scrypt*** algorithm.

Comment: @sanmyth yes, it did.

Comment: Thanks @Nina. I was also able to get it to work. My issue was with the method under base64 python library I was using. Using `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()` did the trick for me.